# Magento2 How to get Store specific Category Id In custom page by using Category URL If same URL exist in both the stores?

Tags: category

I am having the same category in 2 stores and on the custom page, I need category detail as per current store id. I am using the below code to get a category by using the category URL.

In block

public function getCategoryId()

```
{
    $pfCategoryId = $this->categoryFactory->create()
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', 'category-url')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(['entity_id']);
    return $pfCategoryId;
}
```

In phtml

$categoryId =  $block->getCategoryId()->getFirstItem()->getEntityId();

Now I am having 2 stores. How to get store specific category id by using the category URL?

Answer (score 0):

following code will help you to get category collection by url key and store code.

```
protected $_storeManager;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    $data = []
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($data);
}


$pfCategoryId = $this->categoryFactory->create()
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', 'category-url')
    ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore())
    ->addAttributeToSelect(['entity_id']);
return $pfCategoryId;
```

If this help you then hit like.

Thank you,
Hiren Patel

Comment: Hi Hiren, Thank you for your response. I have used the above code but no luck.